# Hasura GraphQL Type Error Inconsistent Object

Tags: graphql, hasura

I'm trying to add the User object to my AuthPayload in Hasura Actions. I'm new to GraphQL and Hasura, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the error I'm getting in the Hasura console.

> Inconsistent object: validation for the given custom types failed
> because the type "User" of the field "user" in the object type
> "AuthPayload" is object type which isn't allowed.

Here is what I have...

**Action definition**

```
type Mutation {
  login(
    email: String!
    password: String!
  ): AuthPayload
}
```

**New types definition**

```
type AuthPayload {
  token: String
  user: User
}
    
type User {
  id: uuid!
  email: String!
  role: String!
}
```

Comment: I never used Actions in hasura but I think error message is clear: you can't use complex type for fields in `AuthPayload`. I suppose that `type AuthPayload { token: String user_id: uuid! email: String! role: String! }` will work. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly indicates that fields in AuthPayload could not be of complex types (objects).

So the fix would be:

```
type AuthPayload {
  token : String
  user_id : uuid!
  email: String!
  role: String!
}
```

put all fields of type `User` inside `AuthPayload`.